# node-metainspetor fetch in Node.js not executing

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, web, web-scraping

I have a simple web scraping script in Node.js that I'm trying to run in a loop:

```
var insp = require('node-metainspector');
var client = new insp("http://www.google.com", { timeout: 99999 });
var sleep = require("thread-sleep");

client.on("fetch", function(){
    console.log("The title is:");
    console.log(client.title);
});

client.on("error", function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});

while(true) {
    console.log("Checking...");
    client.fetch();
    sleep(10000);
}
```

When I run `client.fetch()` outside of the loop it works perfectly fine, but whenever it's in a loop it doesn't work. There's no error thrown (I checked with try-catch).
The rest of the lines in the loop execute. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `thread-sleep` module uses synchronous API (`child_process.execFileSync()`) to "sleep", which is not the recommended way in Node.js. It is more appropriate to use async API to implement what you want. In your case, a simple `setInterval` can do the job:

```
var insp = require('node-metainspector');
var client = new insp("http://www.google.com", { timeout: 99999 });

client.on("fetch", function(){
  console.log("The title is:");
  console.log(client.title);
});

client.on("error", function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});

setInterval(function() {
  console.log("Checking...");
  client.fetch();
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Thank you! Solved. Why is this happening though? Why is the synchronous sleeping "killing" it?

Comment: JavaScript is a single thread environment, any synchronous operation will stop the whole programming from running. This may cause unexpected behaviour. In 99.9% cases, developers should use async operations in node.js